# Automorphisms of a free group on $S$ is essentially a bijection of $S$ extended homomorphically?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, context-free-grammar, free-groups, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a group and consider $A = \text{Aut}(G)$, every $f(x) = g\cdot x$ for a fixed $g \in G$ is in $A$.

But say $G$ is a subgroup of the free group on $\Sigma$, i.e. some $H \leqslant F(\Sigma)$.  Then since an automorphism in $A$ is essentially a bijection of $\Sigma$ extended homomorphically, we can count their number when $\Sigma$ finite: $|A| = |\Sigma|!$ (alphabet size factorial).

Also even "left multiplication by $g$" must always come from some permutation of the alphabet.

Example:

$$
x = aAaA
$$
where $A \to aa$ (not equality!) is a what the variable would expand to in formal language theory.

Then let $g = AaA^{-1}a^{-1}$.  Then $f(x) = g\cdot x = AaaA$, which is intriguing since it means grammar rule rearrangements can be done by a left multiplication action of a group.  However, what permutation of the alphabet does $f(x) = g\cdot x$ correspond to?

I'm thinking I've gone wrong in my reasoning somewhere above.

Comment: I think maybe $g\cdot x = f(x)$ is *not* a homomorphism, but it *is a* bijection?

Comment: Right, multiplication by $g$ is not a homomorphism, as one immediately checks by considering either term of the definition of a homomorphism: it preserves neither the identity nor the multiplication. Furthermore, not every automorphism of a free group comes from a permutation of the alphabet. Why would it?

Comment: Let $G=Free(x,y)$ is there a way to visualize $Aut(G)$ and the composition law on $End(G)=G^2$, how to check if $x\in <u,v>$, and what is the subgroup of $Aut(G)$ generated by $(x,y) \to (y,x), \to (xy,y), \to (x^{-1},y)$ ?

Comment: @KevinCarlson I'm not seeing your last sentence.  If $f: G \to G$ then $f(\sigma_1 \cdots \sigma_{|s|}) = f(s)$, and if $\sigma_i \in \Sigma^{-1}$ then $f(\sigma_i^{-1}) = f(\sigma_i)^{-1}$ since $f$ is a group hom and $\Sigma \subset G$.  So it's homomorphic all the way down to the alphabet which determines completely the automorphism.  SO it's not bijections of alphabet though they *are* determined by what you map the alphabet to.  You're right, nevermind! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, multiplication by any fixed non-identity element of a group on either side will never be an automorphism, because it does not preserve either the identity or the multiplication.

Second, while we have an obvious injective homomorphism from $S_n$ to the automorphism group of the free group on $n$ generators, this embedding is not an isomorphism. For example, the negation automorphism of the group of integers (which is free on one generator) does not arise from a permutation of the generating set.

We also have inner automorphisms of free groups, which generally are not in the image of the embedding because any generator will commute only with its own powers in a free group.

Comment: Thanks!  You are a young genius in math.  I hope your rep here goes through the roof, and that you win a Millenium Prize Problem and a Fields Medal.  :)